# Delete more than one product from shopping cart in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart

I just want to delete multiple products from shopping cart using single click.Thanks in Advance

Comment: For example i want a solution in that like checkbox is there. Which product is checked that should be deleted and remaining product as usual available in shopping cart. Hope now you got exact scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got correct answer of my own question. Just click [DCKAP](http://www.dckap.com/blog/multiple-items-cart-delete-magento-2/).You guys will find with respective blog.
Thanks for all who gave the answer.

Comment: you have to give your answer in details, you cant set any other blog link in your answer, may be possiblity  in future is that  iflink are removed then answer is not found for other users.

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2 comes with a "Clear Shopping Cart" button out of the box:

[image]

However, **this button is hidden on the Luma theme**, I'm not entirely sure why. I tested it and it works fine though.

Answer (score 2):

You have to just set display block to get **clear shopping cart** button visible in checkout cart page.

```
 .cart-container .form-cart .actions.main .clear{ display:none}
```

Replace with,

```
 .cart-container .form-cart .actions.main .clear{ display:block }
```

You have seen one Clear Shopping Cart Button below cart item.

Upon click on button all product are removed from cart.

This is the default functionality of cart page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the question is multiple product deletion. It should be one, two or all cart product,  but you are giving a solution for all cart product delete. For example i want a solution in that like checkbox is there. Which product is checked that should be deleted and remaining product as usual available in shopping cart. Hope now you got exact scenario